# Algoritmo de números primos só funciona para o primeiro número verificado

Tags: java, for

Criei um programa de verificação de números primos e nele recebo `n` entradas. Ou seja, `n` é o número de casos de teste. O problema é que no primeiro caso de teste tudo funciona bem. Já no segundo em diante o programa erra em dizer se o número é primo ou não.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int contador = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int v = sc.nextInt();

        for(int j = 1; j <= v; j++){
            if(v % j == 0){
                contador++;
            }
        }
        if(contador == 2){
            System.out.println("PRIME");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("NOT PRIME");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Como consertar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A inicialização do contador está no lugar errado, toda vez que for verificar um novo número, o contador tem que ser zerado. Aproveitei e fiz uma otimização para não perder tempo quando ele já sabe que não é primo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int v = sc.nextInt();
            int contador = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= v; j++) {
                if (v % j == 0) {
                    contador++;
                    if (contador == 3) break;
                }
            }
            if (contador == 2) System.out.println("PRIME");
            else System.out.println("NOT PRIME");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/851dY0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pieesqqw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Prime.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado, bigown!