# Números Primos em JAVA

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um trabalho em *Java*, onde o usuário deve informar números menores que 20, e depois esse programa deve dizer quais deves números são primos. Não sei se minha lógica está certa, mas no console não aparece nada, fica apenas vazio.

Segue o código:

```
package javatrabalho;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class trabalhopronto {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String entrada1;
    int numero, contador;
    numero = 0;
    contador = 1;

    if (numero > 20) {
        System.out.println("Informe um numero menor que 20");
    }

    while (numero <= 20) {

        entrada1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe um numero menor que 20");
        numero = Integer.parseInt(entrada1);

        // saber se um numero é primo
        if (numero < contador) {

            if (numero % contador == 0) {
                contador = contador + 1;
            }

            if (contador > 2) {
                System.out.println("O numero é primo" + numero);
            } else {
                System.out.println("O numero não é primo" + numero);
            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Além do problema do `contador` já citado na resposta do André abaixo, o algoritmo para determinar se o número é primo não está certo. Existem vários algoritmos para isso, alguns mais ingênuos (fazem um `for` de 1 em 1 até n), e outros um pouco mais "espertos" (exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111675)

Comment: Também encontrei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138348/127729) sobre números primos, da uma conferida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá [ayanami001](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/163092/ayanami001), seja bem vinda ao [pt.stackoverflow.com](https://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Analisei o seu código e reparei que o problema está na seguinte condição:
 `if (numero < contador) { ...`

Não sei se você reparou, mas ao iniciar a aplicação, a variável `contador` está sendo inicializada com o valor **1** e sempre que você digitar um valor maior que **0** e menor ou igual a **20**, a aplicação jamais irá percorrer esse bloco de código dentro do `if` citado acima. Isso explica o porque que a sua aplicação não exibe nada no seu console nesse cenário.

Dica: Também reparei que você não utilizando uma das [regras e convenções de nomenclatura de classes Java](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/nomenclatura.php)  ¹(**toda** classe deve começar com uma letra maiúscula e, de preferência, não pode conter letras não ASCII) no seu projeto, claro que isso não impedirá a execução da sua classe Java, porém, aconselho começar à se adaptar nesses detalhes que são extremamente importantes.

Comment: Eu não chamaria de regra mas sim convenção,.

Comment: Concordo Isaac, valeu por opinar nesse detalhe. O termo regra deixa implícito que só há a possibilidade tal maneira :)